# DialogWindow cause a StackOverflow Exception

Tags: c#

I have a dialog window with three buttons to select the Data Source in Application, also I have an Accept button and Cancel Button, but when I press any button the program cause a stack overflow exception.

```
public int SelDataSource
    {
        get { return SelDataSource; }
        set { SelDataSource = value; }
    }

    public formSelDataSource()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
    }

    private void rbtnSQLServer_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SelDataSource = (int)DataSources.SQLServer;
    }

    private void rbtnAccess_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SelDataSource = (int)DataSources.Access;
    }

    private void rbtnMySQL_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SelDataSource = (int)DataSources.MySQL;
    }

    private void btnAceptar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
    }

    private void formSelDataSource_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DialogResult == DialogResult.None)
            e.Cancel = true;
    }

    private void SelDataSourceButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
    }
```

have anybody a solution?

Comment: Hi, please include the exception and any more information that can help see where exactly your code is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the form. The property `SelDataSource` has an infinite recursion in it (the setter keeps calling itself, as does the getter).

You can use an auto-property instead:

```
public int SelDataSource { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int SelDataSource
{
    get { return SelDataSource; }
    set { SelDataSource = value; }
}
```

That is a self-reference. You are trying to make a *property with backing field*, but here the "backing field" is the property itself. When you access the property, it calls the `get` block, which accesses the property, which calls the `get` block, et caetera.
You can either create a backing field, or replace it by an auto-property like this:

```
public int SelDataSource { get; set; }
```